# Setting field2=field1 in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am unable to update my document when I run
`db.xx.updateOne({_id: ObjectId(""}, {$set: {lq: uq})` I get the error `uncaught exception: ReferenceError: uq is not defined`

uq field exists and contains integers, not sure why it don't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "field1": "$field2"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LvNzANIz9X-)

Comment: It didn't work. It set the value for 'lq' to '$uq' not actual uq value

Comment: you need `[` & `]`